# Java jpackage native packaging, WiX tools not found error

Tags: java, packaging, java-14

I am using the beta [jpackage tool](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/03/jep-343-jpackage/) (JEP 343) that comes with the [JDK14](https://jdk.java.net/14/) early access build.

I have run the following .bat script in windows

```
"%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jpackage" ^
--name NAME ^
--dest store/ ^
--input store/package/ ^
--main-jar MAIN_JAR.jar ^
--main-class library.MAIN_CLASS^
```

I am receiving the following error when running the script.

> WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.jpackage
>
> Can not find WiX tools (light.exe, candle.exe) 
>   Download WiX 3.0 or later from https://wixtoolset.org and add it to the PATH. 
>   Error: Invalid or unsupported type: [null]

I have download WiX311.exe and tried putting it in the same folder as the jpackage.exe and in the same folder as the MAIN_JAR.jar and neither has solved this issue.

So my question is what is "the PATH" that I need to add it to in order to get this to package?

Answer (score 8):

1. Download latest WIX Toolset ([Link](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases))
2. Install wix311.exe

   [image]

Note:

- In case if your are downloading the portable version , then set the
  path in  environment variable.
- Make sure you have installed Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 ([Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=22))

Comment: I install the wix with command below:

Answer (score 3):

1. Path is an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).
2. You need to run wix311.exe and then click on the install button. Then all the appropriate tools will be installed and added to PATH.

Comment: Thank you for the post! I will see if this solves my issue!

Answer (score 3):

I installed the wix with the command below:

```
dotnet tool install wix -g --add-source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' --ignore-failed-sources
```

Then I checked if it was installed and if it was added to PATH.

```
> wix --version
4.0.0+8c757c0f
```

But the jpackage continues with the same error:

```
❯ jpackage --type exe --dest .\target\jpackage --input .\target\bundles\my-app --main-jar 'my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' --jlink-options --bind-services --verbose
[10:45:06.832] Running candle.exe
[10:45:06.883] jdk.jpackage.internal.PackagerException: Error: Invalid or unsupported type: [exe]
        at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.generateBundle(Arguments.java:694)
        at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.processArguments(Arguments.java:565)
        at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.main.Main.execute(Main.java:92)
        at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.main.Main.main(Main.java:53)
[10:45:06.873] Can not find WiX tools (light.exe, candle.exe)
[10:45:06.881] Download WiX 3.0 or later from https://wixtoolset.org and add it to the PATH.
```

My JDK is version 20.

Comment: I have similar problem. Wix is installed and visible (i can run wix --version) but when executing jpcakage It returns the same error. Wix itself is in PATH but I cant see neither light.exe nor candle.exe.

Comment: From: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/fourthree/ -> "in WiX v3, you might build by calling Candle.exe one or more times to compile your authoring and then calling Light.exe to link and bind the compiled authoring into an .msi package. In WiX v4 using wix.exe, that's one command: wix build -o product.msi product.wxs". It means that jpackage still uses WiX 3.0, when WiX 4.0 you have installed has all those tools merged into single wix.exe meaning that it cannot be used. Uninstall WiX 4.0 and install WiX 3.0.

Comment: @Fabricio Pereira   Any update on this?

Comment: Only works with WiX v3.